# Put small icon inside listview JQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

Seems I can't put the icon correctly, can someone help me out?
JQuery Mobile version: 1.4.2

```
<div data-role="page" id="pageone">
<div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
<h2>List With Thumbnails and Text</h2>
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
<li>
<a href="#">
<img src="chrome.png">
<h2>Google Chrome</h2>
<p><img class='ui-icon-home ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-icon-left'/> Google Chrome is a free, open-source web browser. Released in 2008.</p>
</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#">
<img src="firefox.png">
<h2>Mozilla Firefox</h2>
<p>Firefox is a web browser from Mozilla. Released in 2004.</p>
</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Result:

[image]

I try to use this but doesn't work.

```
<span><i class='ui-icon-home ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-icon-left'>Text</i></span>
```

Comment: What you need exactly..remove the default icon and show this home icon or some other

Comment: I need to put the icon beside the "Google Chrome is a free..." word.
But you can see the current alignment is gone to center even I put the icon position is left.

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/QETcC/ tell what changes need to be done

Comment: The text and icon should be in the same line

Comment: checkis it ok http://jsfiddle.net/Fw9B7/2/ or exactly you want

Comment: Ya but why there is another button there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the icon inline with the text and not a button, you can accomplish it like this.

First add a span for the icon with `class="ui-icon-home ui-btn-icon-notext inlineIcon"`:

```
<p>
    <span class="ui-icon-home ui-btn-icon-notext inlineIcon"></span>
    Google Chrome is a free, open-source web browser. Released in 2008.
</p>
```

Then we add the folowing CSS:

```
li p {
    line-height: 24px;
}
.inlineIcon {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: 6px;
}
```

The P line-height makes room vertically for the icon, while the inlineIcon class places the icon correctly.

If you do not want the gray disk and would prefer a plain black version of the icon, you would add the ui-alt-icon class to the span to make it black, and the CSS would be:

```
.inlineIconNoDisk {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: 6px;
}
.inlineIconNoDisk:after {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/4Wm8c/2/)**

And a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

Try this code it will work

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

    <div data-role="page" id="pageone">
  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <h2>List With Thumbnails and Text</h2>
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
      <li>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="chrome.png"/>

        <h2>Google Chrome</h2>

<div class="ui-grid-a">
    <div class="ui-block-a" style="width:30%;"><button data-icon='home' data-iconpos="notext"></button></div>
    <div class="ui-block-b" style="width:70%;"> <p>Google Chrome is a free, open-source web browser. Released in 2008.</p></div></div>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="firefox.png"/>
        <h2>Mozilla Firefox</h2>



            <div class="ui-grid-a">
    <div class="ui-block-a" style="width:30%"><button data-icon='home' data-iconpos="notext"></button></div>
    <div class="ui-block-b" style="width:70%;padding-bottom:5%;"> <p>Firefox is a web browser from Mozilla. Released in 2004.</p></div>

</div>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Refer this [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Fw9B7/4/)

Comment: Any solution beside using button/any click-able tag?

Comment: I want to do something like this but I can't make it work http://i61.tinypic.com/b8sm8j.png

Comment: these and all are anchor tag with icons..you are not able to do with anchor inside anchor like you expect.

Comment: What can I change to make it all fit? Because the current solution doesn't fit the text with the image....

Comment: if you want like fit image with text do some CSS works or other wise use button to get text and image in same.

Comment: What kind of CSS code I should add to align? Can you help me in this? Thanks in advance!